# Convert Encrypt code in java to Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, aes, sha

I have been trying to convert a code for encrypt in java to ruby, but I am not able to do it completely. I getting different values.

```
   passphrase = passphrase + STATIC_KEY;
   byte[] key = passphrase.getBytes("UTF-8");

   MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
   key = sha.digest(key);
   key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
   SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
   IvParameterSpec initialisationVector = new IvParameterSpec(
           new byte[16]);
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, initialisationVector);

   byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

   return SimpleCrypto.toHex(encryptedData);
```

Can anyone let me know, how this can be done in it ruby.

```
  unencrypted = "passphrase"
  c = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
  c.encrypt
  c.key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('secret_key')[0...32]
  e = c.update(unencrypted)
  e << c.final
  return e
```

Comment: if my answer was correct let me know

Comment: @railrailrail, I have posted my answer. I tried ur code. `hex_to_bin` conversion of key was the missing piece. pls check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypt Code:

```
def aes(key,string)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.padding = 1
  cipher.key = hex_to_bin(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('secret_key')[0..32])
  cipher_text = cipher.update(string)
  cipher_text << cipher.final
  return bin_to_hex(cipher_text).upcase
end
```

Decrypt Code:

```
def aes_decrypt(key, encrypted)
  encrypted = hex_to_bin(encrypted.downcase)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-128-cbc")
  cipher.decrypt
  cipher.padding = 1
  cipher.key = hex_to_bin(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('secret_key')[0..32])
  d = cipher.update(encrypted)
  d << cipher.final
end
```

hex_to_bin and bin_to_hex

```
def hex_to_bin(str)
  [str].pack "H*"
end

def bin_to_hex(s)
  s.unpack('C*').map{ |b| "%02X" % b }.join('')
end
```

In My case, The java code was using default initialization vector, So I did not set any iv, Also, there was `hex_to_bin` was a missing piece there. So after that, all started working properly.

I hope it helps someone if they come across this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'openssl'
```

## Encrypt:

```
unencrypted = "I am a secret!"
```

initialize the Cipher for encrypt

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
cipher.encrypt
```

create the key using SHA1

```
key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('secret_key')[0...32]
cipher.key = key
```

create the initialisationVector with an input

```
iv = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('secret_iv')[0...32]
cipher.iv = iv
```

**or** create a random initialisationVector

```
iv = cipher.random_iv
```

run the encryption

```
encrypted = cipher.update(unencrypted) + cipher.final
```

## Decrypt:

initialize the Cipher for decrypt

```
decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES.new(128, :CBC)
decipher.decrypt
```

load the key and initialisationVector

```
decipher.key = key
decipher.iv = iv
```

decrypt the plaintext

```
plain = decipher.update(encrypted) + decipher.final
```

## Does it match?

```
puts unencrypted == plain #=> true
```

For more information look at the Ruby Docs for the Class - [OpenSSL::Cipher](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html)

Comment: Hey Man, I was able to figure out code. +1 for your efforts. I will try your code too.