# How to store variables passed to a Ruby class when initializing securely so that they can be accessed by other methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to know how to **securely** store the parameters passed into a Ruby class when initializing as shown below...

```
 myclass = MyClass.new(auth_token)
```

... So that it can be accessed by other methods in the class to perform their actions like this:

```
myclass.do_something
```

The parameters that I pass are very sensitive so the security should be the highest priority. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Adrian Sorry im not such an expert. That's why i said `securely` without specifics. I need to make sure that no one can temper with those data. No one can get those data except for the methods inside the class.

Comment: Tell me specifically who or what you don't want to be able to access the data. If you are talking about other code running in the same ruby process, then what you are trying to do is impossible.

Comment: @Adrian Im trying to initialize this class when the application starts. Will it be insecure?

Comment: It really just depends what you mean by "insecure"... you could always just make sure your computer has a password on it...

Comment: @Adrian No no... any intruders. For example the values that I pass are same as the paypal login details for the payment gateway.

Comment: Define "intruders." I'm sorry that I'm probably sounding like a broken record, but words like "secure" and "intruders" really don't have any meaning without more context. Chances are that you don't need to modify your ruby code to make it secure, but instead you just need to secure whatever computer or server it's running on.

Comment: @Adrian Yea you might be right :-) Sorry Im also not a security expert. What I just want is to make it secure from any threats that it can face because it's very sensitive data. Have no much idea about the threats that it could face. :-(

Comment: @EApubs: "Have no much idea about the threats that it could face." – Well, for example, someone could break into your home, kidnap your wife and kids and force you to hand over the root password. Someone might break into the datacenter and steal the server. Someone might zap the server with ultra-hard X-rays, which will "burn" the current contents of the memory into the RAM chips, thus making it possible to retrieve it even hours later after stealing the server. Someone might break into the datacenter and install a network sniffer at the core switch. Someone might pay off the cleaning lady …

Comment: … in your office to install a keylogger in your computer. Someone might kidnap *you* and force you to hand over the root password. Someone might threaten to bomb the datacenter unless you hand over the data. Someone might hack PayPal and steal the data from there, without even attacking you directly. And so on and so forth …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt the value before you store it, then store the encrypted value.

Then when you want to retrieve it you would decrypt it and then display the value.

You can **use AES-128/AES-256 to encrypt** the data using the ruby `OpenSSL::Cipher` and `Digest` libraries

[Here is a post I made showing how to use the libraries to encrypt-decrypt whatever values you want.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28312139/737275)

> Keep in mind you will need to keep track of your **key** and
>   **initialization vector**

Comment: Great. How can I make it available to other private methods in the same class?

Comment: by writing methods to handle the encryption/decryption and then calling them in the other private functions or any other way you want to link the methods together. it is tough to answer when you are not more descriptive with what you are trying to code.

Answer (score 0):

If intruders encompasses people who can run ruby code in your process then this cannot be done.

Ruby allows private methods to be called, instance variables to be read and so on. Even if you encrypted the data, someone who can run code inside your ruby process could monkey patch the encryption methods to not do anything or gain access to the encryption keys

Comment: So no other option other than defining them as instance variables right?

Comment: Nope. I'd worry more about how this data is stored on disk (if it is at all) than how it is stored in memory.

Comment: Ah yep. Thats a big issue

Comment: Im thinking of storing it in a configuration file using the `figaro` gem. Is it secure enough? I will be able to access it with `ENV` command

Comment: Secure enough against what? What is your threat model?